# php keeping track of random condition

Tags: php, mysql, random

At the moment I've 3 conditions that need to be met randomly one time on 3 pages. So if page one gets randomly the second condition, page 2 can only get randomly condition 1 or 3 and so on. For that I write to a database (I already using a database to log activities) and call it on the other pages to see which condition already has been met on previous pages.

I created for the first page a random function:`<?php $rand = rand(1, 3); ?>`

The second page:

```
    if ($row['manip_1'] == 1){
        $man = rand(2,3);
    } elseif ($row['manip_1'] == 2){    //should do randomly 1 or 3,
        $man_a = rand(1,2);         //but don't know how to skip #2 in a 
            if($man_a == 2){    //random function, so solved it like this
                $man = 3;
            } else {
                $man = 1;
            }
    } else {
        $man = rand(1,2);
    }
```

The third page:

```
    if ($row['manip_1'] == 1 && $row['manip_2'] == 2){
        $man = 3;
    } elseif ($row['manip_1'] == 1 && $row['manip_2'] == 3){
        $man = 2;
    } elseif ($row['manip_1'] == 2 && $row['manip_2'] == 1){
        $man = 3;
    } elseif ($row['manip_1'] == 2 && $row['manip_2'] == 3){
        $man = 1;
    } elseif ($row['manip_1'] == 3 && $row['manip_2'] == 1){
        $man = 2;
    } else {
        $man = 1;
    }
```

The problem now is that I suddenly need to have a fourth page. Meaning that there also should be a fourth condition. That also means that the number of possibilities are now 25 on the last page. I can program it again like I did before, but I was wondering if there is not any more convenient way to program a random condition that is dependent on the conditions of previous pages. During the 4 pages each condition can only be shown once.

Answer (score 2):

Define an array of the conditions, and store them in the session, e.g.

```
$conditions = array(1,2,3,4);
$_SESSION['conditions'] = $conditions;
```

Randomization is easy:

```
array_shuffle($_SESSION['conditions']);
```

Then on each of the individual pages, you just pop off one of those values from the session:

```
<?php
# page 1
session_start();

$random_condition = array_pop($_SESSION['conditions']);
```

and do so for all the other pages:

```
<?php
#page n
session_start();
$random_condition = array_pop($_SESSION['conditions']);
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: do I need to update the session variable after a pop off on each page?

Comment: hmm...I guess I could also just shuffle once and then call on every page a fixed position in the array. Don't know why I was thinking so difficult. Thanks!